# Knox rule updates on Dataproc not working

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, apache-knox

I updated some Knox rules in a live Dataproc cluster and restarted Knox, but the new rules didn't work, old rules were still used. What's the possible cause and how do I resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean up the Knox deployment cache in `/usr/lib/knox/data/deployments/`.

Full steps (run as root):

```
systemctl stop knox

# Update Knox rules in /etc/knox/conf and/or /usr/lib/knox/data/services
...

rm -rf /usr/lib/knox/data/deployments/*

systemctl start knox
```